# What is the meaning of this short code?

Tags: c, string, printf

I have this code. It prints ABBAA and I have no idea why. How does it behave with 16961? What is the meaning of this number?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
short a[]={'A',16961,16706,65,16961,16706};
printf("%s\n",&((char*)a)[2]);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). Run the program step by step in a debugger (`gdb`). Read about [endianess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) & [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Comment: See that casting to `char*` in there? Think about what a two-byte value like  `16961` would be if split up into its two bytes, and see e.g. [this ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/).

Comment: It's a good way to test your machine endianness. ABBAA is little-endian, and I guess you'd have BAAB on a big-endian machine (both having 16-bits for *shorts*). (hint: strings closing character is a `0` in C)

Answer (score 2):

You have an array of `short`s (very commonly 2 bytes long), so let convert them to `char`s (bytes). We will use the hexadecimal basis for the sake of simplicity (as it is very convenient to manipulate bytes).

Decimal `16961` equals hexadecimal `4241` (commonly written as `0x4241`), `16706` equals `4142`, and `65` is `0041`. Ascii(0x41)=Ascii(65) is `A` and ASCII(0x42) is `B`.
`&((char*)a)[2]` points to the third byte of the table, and we know that the first printed char is `A`.

Now lets see what could be in memory:

- if your machine is a big endian model you will have bytes NUL, `A`, `B`, `A`, `A`, `B`, NUL, `A`,
- if your machine is a little endian one, you will have `A`, NUL, `A`, `B`, `B`, `A`, `A`, NUL

So we know that your machine is a little endian one. The `printf` write every `chars` from the third up to the the first encountered NUL: `ABBAA`

Comment: I've read this 5 times and I still don't get where the NUL came from.

Comment: short are (usually) 16 bits long, that means that any number stored in a short is written using 16 bits! So if I need to store the value 65 (`A` in Ascii), that value stored in a short equals to 0000000001000001 (binary). Now 16 bits makes 2 bytes (a byte is 8 bits long), so we have byte 00000000 and byte 01000001, in decimal bytes 0 and 65 or in hexa bytes 0x00 and 0x41. NUL is the null bytes (all bits zeroed).

Comment: You can park a tiny car in a standard park location, the "extra space" is there, free. A park location is always the same size, but the cars may vary. Tiny values leaves many zeros on the left...

Comment: @avital You stored 'A' (8 bits) in a short (16 bits), the remaining 8 bits are all zeros...